# Dafny, post condition does not hold after loop

Tags: verification, dafny

In the following method, Dafny reports that the postcondition might not hold, even though I am quite sure that it does.

```
method toArrayConvert(s:seq<int>) returns (a:array<int>)
    requires |s| > 0
    ensures |s| == a.Length
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> s[i] == a[i]  // This is the postcondition that might not hold.
{
    a := new int[|s|];
    var i:int := 0;
    while i < |s|
        decreases |s| - i
        invariant 0 <= i <= |s|
    {
        a[i] := s[i];
        i := i + 1;
    }

    return a;  // A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the postcondition does always hold, but Dafny cannot tell!

That's because you're missing a loop invariant annotation such as

```
invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> s[j] == a[j]
```

After adding that line to the loop, the method verifies.

For more explanation about why Dafny sometimes reports errors on correct programs, see the (brand new) [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/wiki/FAQ). For more about loop invariants, see the corresponding section in the rise4fun [guide](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide).

Comment: Thanks, James :) I totally forgot about invariants